# Pythagoras Tree failling on level 2 and more, why?

Tags: haskell, tree, gloss

So we are trying to build a Pythagoras `Tree` using `gloss`, and it fails level 2 and next ones (only works level 0 and 1).

Here is the code:

```
data FTree a b = Unit b | Comp a (FTree a b) (FTree a b) deriving (Eq,Show)
type PTree = FTree Square Square
type Square = Float

generatePTree n = aux n 100 where 
   aux :: Int -> Float -> PTree 
   aux 0 x = Unit x
   aux n x = Comp x (aux (n-1) (x * (sqrt(2)/2))) (aux (n-1) (x * (sqrt(2)/2))) 

drawPTree :: PTree -> [Picture]
drawPTree p = aux p (0,0) 0 where
      aux :: PTree -> (Float, Float) -> Float -> [Picture]
      aux (Unit c) (x,y) ang = [Translate x y (Rotate ang (square c))]
      aux (Comp c l r) (x,y) ang = [Translate x y (Rotate ang (square c))]++(aux l (x - somaX c,y + somaY c) (ang - 45)) ++ (aux r (x + somaX c,y + somaY c) (ang + 45)) 
                  where somaX c = c/2 
                        somaY c = c + sqrt(((c * (sqrt 2))/4)^2 - ((sqrt (c^2 + c^2)) / 4)^2)   

window = (InWindow "CP" (800,800) (0,0))
square s = rectangleSolid s s

main = animate window white draw
    where
    pics = drawPTree (generatePTree 2)
    draw t = Pictures $ pics
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'failing'? Is its output wrong? Is there an error? Please elaborate on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies solely in your `drawPTree` function, and I'll address the problems I found in it, into a working solution.

We start with your current solution:

```
drawPTree :: PTree -> [Picture]
drawPTree p = aux p (0,0) 0 where
      aux :: PTree -> (Float, Float) -> Float -> [Picture]
      aux (Unit c) (x,y) ang = [Translate x y (Rotate ang (square c))]
      aux (Comp c l r) (x,y) ang = [Translate x y (Rotate ang (square c))]++(aux l (x - somaX c,y + somaY c) (ang - 45)) ++ (aux r (x + somaX c,y + somaY c) (ang + 45)) 
                  where somaX c = c/2 
                        somaY c = c + sqrt(((c * (sqrt 2))/4)^2 - ((sqrt (c^2 + c^2)) / 4)^2)
```

First up, let's deal with `somaX` and `somaY`, which based on the implementation are the translations to `x` and `y` along the direction of the current branch.
Note that you can define them as variables instead of functions, since `c` is already in scope, also, `sqrt(((c * (sqrt 2))/4)^2 - ((sqrt (c^2 + c^2)) / 4)^2)=0` hence `somaY = c` (this can be seen from the diagram of Pythagoras Tree):

```
drawPTree :: PTree -> [Picture]
drawPTree p = aux p (0,0) 0 where
      aux :: PTree -> (Float, Float) -> Float -> [Picture]
      aux (Unit c) (x,y) ang = [Translate x y (Rotate ang (square c))]
      aux (Comp c l r) (x,y) ang = [Translate x y (Rotate ang (square c))] ++
                                   (aux l (x - somaX,y + somaY) (ang - 45)) ++ 
                                   (aux r (x + somaX,y + somaY) (ang + 45)) 
                  where somaX = c/2 
                        somaY = c
```

This code still won't give you the correct result, simply because `Translate` works on the global coordinate system, so we need to give it the correct points. Luckily we can easily get the correct transformation by simple trigonometry

```
drawPTree :: PTree -> [Picture]
drawPTree p = aux p (0,0) 0 where
      aux :: PTree -> (Float, Float) -> Float -> [Picture]
      aux (Unit c) (x,y) ang = [Translate x y (Rotate ang (square c))]
      aux (Comp c l r) (x,y) ang = [Translate x y (Rotate ang (square c))] ++
                                    (aux l (x + somaXLeft,y + somaYLeft) (ang - 45)) ++ 
                                    (aux r (x + somaXRight,y + somaYRight) (ang + 45)) 
                  where somaX = c/2
                        somaY = c
                        angRads = ang * pi / 180
                        branchToGlobal angle (dx,dy) = 
                          (dx * cos angle + dy * sin angle, dy * cos angle - dx * sin angle)
                        (somaXLeft, somaYLeft) = branchToGlobal angRads (-somaX, somaY)
                        (somaXRight, somaYRight) = branchToGlobal angRads (somaX, somaY)
```

And this will indeed render the tree correctly.